# Fetching from mysql and storing in an array in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, database

```
$query= "Select * from std";
                $res= mysqli_query($con, $query);
                $idArray=array();
                $i=0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $idArray[$i]=htmlentities($row["id"]);
                    $i++;
                }
                for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
                    echo $idArray[j]."asd<br>";  
                }
```

In output it shows only "asd" 5 times as i have five records but i does not showing the id's of those records,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: `$query= "Select id from std";`.... think smarter...

Comment: will it return an array ?

Comment: yeah., it will also return an array,, but only containing the `id` field...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a dollar sign on the echo-row:

```
echo $idArray[j]."asd<br>";
```

Should be

```
echo $idArray[$j]."asd<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks, much respect, Actually i have switched from java to php, $$$$ are annoying me,, :) ,

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `count` of `$idArray` and pass it to for loop

```
for($j=0;$j<count($idArray);$j++){
    echo $idArray[$j]."asd<br>";  
}
```

But why are you using different for loop .... you could echo in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query= "Select * from std";
$res= mysqli_query($con, $query);
$idArray=array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    $idArray[] =htmlentities($row["id"]);
}

for($j=0;$j<sizeof($idArray);$j++){
    echo $idArray[$j]."asd<br>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

mysql_select_db('test_db',$db); 

$data = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_table"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) {

   $data[] = $row; 

}

print_r($data);

?>
```

Example Taken From : 
http://arjun.net.in/displaying-mysql-table-records-in-unordered-list-format-using-php/

Comment: Try to understand the question...is this meets requirement ?